# Please, can anyone help me understand the meaning of the word 'wrap' in this sentence:

Tags: meaning

Jerking time to full deceleration (after **full** **wrap** of ego vehicle and cut-in vehicle, road friction 1,0)
It is from a new UNECE Regulation, no 157, about automated driving systems.

Comment: Please provide a link to the source. What have you looked up? Where? Does the Regulation contain a glossary?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in its source material (not given) it is almost certainly a misprint. It would also seem to be involve a non-standard acronym.

Answer (score 1):

I found the document: it's a [PDF](https://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trans/doc/2020/wp29grva/GRVA-06-09e.pdf) and the phrase appears in the table on page 4.

*Wrap* appears to be a misprint. The previous page contains a diagram

[image]

which contains the phrases *xx% Rap, 100% Rap* and *Release accelerator pedal*.

The quoted phrase *full wrap* should presumably be *full rap* and means ***full release of the accelerator pedal.***

Comment: Not on-topic. rap is in-house.

Comment: Indeed. It's a sub-genre.

Comment: Is it helpful for a moderator to knowingly answer an off-topic question? Doesn't this severely undermine the credibility of ELU? How can one realistically help police the site?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How do you know it's off-topic until *wrap* has been looked at? It may well have been a new meaning of *wrap,* akin to the jargon of all-over advertising. In this case, it isn't. Your comments are benefiting from hindsight.

Comment: Is it useful for a mod to give an answer (rather than a short helpful comment) explaining that 'wrap' should probably be the non-standard acronym 'rap'? Haven't you checked for a 'wrap' neologism?